# Remove EXIF data in Python?

Tags: python, exif

Is there any python library/easy way  to strip EXIF data from a JPEG without a significant performance/image quality impact? I searched for one but couldn't find much.  I'm hosting some user upload images and would like to strip this data for privacy/safety reasons.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
image = GExiv2.Metadata('sample.jpg')
image.clear_exif()
image.clear_xmp()
image.save_file()
```

with gexiv2 library: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gexiv2

Comment: Does not work if the meta data is already too big. The error, `GLib.Error: GExiv2: Failed to read image data (14)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone's looking for a existing (python) implementation or a higher-level solution with more features, here's a link to the [Metadata Anonymization Toolkit](https://mat.boum.org/).

It may be interesting to look at the [`images.py` file](https://0xacab.org/jvoisin/mat2/blob/master/libmat2/images.py), which includes useful information.